# Joomla doesn't show images in frontend

Tags: html, css, image, templates, joomla

I created a Joomla template and in my index.php file there are images.

So the template work and everything is shown up exept the images. There is only the picture symbol.

I'm using the newest version of Joomla. Joomla 3.8.6
I placed the images in the Joomla images foolder and also in the template images folder.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The path to the images is wrong. Check your browser developer tools and it will tell you what path it is trying to load the images from.

Crucially though, you should not be putting images in index.php, that is not how Joomla works. It is a CMS, you don't hardcode asset paths in the index template.